# When we calculate the total force of an object falling through a fluid we calculate it by the formula weight - upthrust

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, viscosity

Why when we calculate net force on an object falling through a  a fluid we generally do not include viscous force?

Comment: If it is not moving, how would there be viscous force?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, my question is when the object is falling through a fluid we calculate the net force of the object by weight- upthrust and generally not include viscous force? Why? Please tell me the answer

Comment: but we often do, when that is needed?

Comment: But how can we know that when there is need of it and when there is not. Please answer my question

Comment: In physics/engineering "You need when you need" holds. What are you doing? Anyway, as a rule of thumb, you can't neglect viscous stress if you're dealing with bluff object or if you're interested in the evaluation of drag, even for streamlined bodies at small angle of incidence, and no flow separation occurs.

Comment: Who says we do not include the viscous force?

Answer (score 0):

In physics/engineering "You need when you need" holds. So it really depends on what you're doing.

Anyway, as a rule of thumb, you can't neglect viscous stress:

- if the **Reynolds number** of the problem is **small**, and viscosity dominates over inertia;
- even if the Reynolds number is high enough for the inertia to overcome viscous stress in large regions of the fluid, if you're dealing with **bluff bodies**;
- even if the Reynolds number is high, and you're dealing with with streamlined bodies at small angle of incidence, and no flow separation occurs,  if you're interested in an **accurate evaluation of drag**. This is the case of airplanes, where you're mainly interested in **efficiency** to reduce fuel consumption and thus cost and environmental pollution: in cruise, lift is given by the weight of the plane (since vertical equilibrium must hold), while drag depends on the the aerodynamics of the plane and must be equilibrated by engine thrust.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for practical purposes we definitely need to consider the fluid drag force. It might just be the case that the particular problem that you are solving requires it to be ignored.

Generally in high school physics, we generally ignore all dissipative effects such as fluid drag, friction unless mentioned otherwise. If it is not given in the question about drag force, ignore it's effects.